# ToolkitScriptManager is throwing exception on calling Page_ClientValidate

Tags: asp.net

I am using AjaxToolkit 4.0 which suggests to use ToolkitScriptManager in place of ScriptManager. But when I am using ToolkitScriptManager, it throws javascript exception when Page_ClientValidate() in called from javascript. However, this error is not coming when ScriptManager is used.

Can anybody tell me how to make Page_ClientValidate() run when using ToolkitScriptManager?

Thanks:
Ashwani

Comment: It hits the debugger Page_ClientValidate() at showing "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected" in error pop-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use some of the extra parameters. Mine normally looks like this:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" CombineScripts="false" EnablePartialRendering="true" AllowCustomErrorsRedirect="false" />
```

Look in something like firebug, to see if the scripts are loading properly.

Comment: what did firebug show? was it partial downloading the toolkit javascript files?

Comment: I got the issue, the issue was coming as there were no active validators on the page, so the function was not there. Thanks